# Will there be Rust APIs for state-of-the-art solvers?

Tags: solver, api

The Rust programming language is gaining popularity. As the title says, I wonder if state-of-the-art, say MILP, solvers will eventually release APIs for the Rust programming language. Solvers such as Cplex and Gurobi have APIs for some of the most used programming languages, including, C++, Java, Python, R, Matlab. As far as I know, these do not have Rust APIs.

Should we expect any Rust API in the near future? And what are the reasons in favor or against that?

(To keep the question more specific, I would limit the scope to Cplex and Gurobi).

Answer (score 12):

The upcoming 10.1 version of Mosek includes a fully documented [Rust API](https://docs.mosek.com/10.1/rustapi/index.html). It is currently in beta mode.
At our GitHub page you find more info about [Rust and Mosek](https://github.com/MOSEK/mosek.rust).

Comment: Thanks @ErlingMOSEK, I look forward to giving it a try.

Answer (score 8):

This is what @mattmilten mentioned in the Gurobi [forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360057920492-Rust-API).

> There is no official native Rust API for Gurobi, yet. There are tool
> to generate C bindings for Rust that you may be able to use to call
> the Gurobi C API: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen. This is
> similar to what the official APIs do:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this suggestion by @mattmilten, which can indeed be a solution. I believe a disadvantage of this solution, compared to native APIs, is that it requires some degree of confidence in the C programming language (the lack thereof could in fact be one of the reasons one uses Rust) in addition to ensuring that the C-bindings comply with new Gurobi releases. But without anything native, this is indeed interesting.